# If $f\left(f(x+1) + f\left( x + f(x)\right)\right) = x+2$ then what is $f(10)$?

Tags: functional-equations

Let $f : \mathbb Z_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ be a function satisfying $f(1)=1$ and $$f\Biggl(f(x+1) + f\Bigl( x + f(x)\Bigr)\Biggr) = x+2$$
Then what is $f(10)$?

My teacher gave me this problem and I'm quite not sure how to solve this and looking for help here

Comment: By substituting $x=0$ into second equation, $f(2)=2$. Sub. $x=1$, $f(4)=4. I am thinking how to continue from here.

Comment: @TonyMa  How do you get $f(2)=2$?  I thought I had shown that as well, but I lost the thread.  If I plug $x=0$ in to the OP's functional equation I get $f(f(1)+f(f(0)))=f(1+f(f(0)))=2$ but how do we proceed from there?

Comment: @lulu, Oh sorry I think I get wrong. I should really take a paper to solve seriously. Thx so much.

Comment: @TonyMa  Oh, no worries.  Like I said, I also thought I had shown that but I no longer believe what I wrote.

Comment: Are you sure you  aren't also given $f(0)$?  As the problem stands, I can't think of any way to get started.  Of course, I might be missing something.

Comment: I'm thinking the same.

Comment: Can I know the domain of $f$? I think it maybe( just maybe) easier if I know $f$ is defined on $\mathbb Z$, or even just knowing $f(10)$ is defined.

Comment: Can I know, $f(\dots)=x+2$ is forall $x\in\mathbb R$ or forall $x\in\mathbb Z$ or something?

Comment: @lulu no.. the problem only gives f(1)=1..

Comment: If you find a solution, or if your teacher provides one, please come back and post it here.  I really can't see anyway to attack the problem as it stands...if there is a clever trick, I'd like to see it.

Comment: @lulu I already got a solution from my teacher's former student but I think it's wrong....

Comment: Well, if you are so inclined, post it below.  The crowd here will check it out.

Comment: Corresponding AoPS forum https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1607504. It clarifies that domain and codomain are $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

This is (a tad) trickier than it looks. Consider the function $\mathrm f:\Bbb N\mapsto\Bbb N$ given by
$$\mathrm f(n)=\lfloor n\beta\rfloor+1,$$
where $\beta=\dfrac{\sqrt 5-1}2$ satisfies $\beta^2+\beta=1$.

Clearly $\mathrm f(1)=1$.

*Claim*: $\mathrm f(n+\mathrm f(n))=n+1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Since $\beta$ is irrational, 
$$n\beta<\lfloor n\beta\rfloor+1<n\beta+1,\quad\textrm{so that}\quad n\beta<\mathrm f(n)<n\beta+1.$$
Similarly 
$$(n+\mathrm f(n))\beta<\mathrm f(n+\mathrm f(n))<(n+\mathrm f(n))\beta+1.$$
Thus 
$$(n+n\beta)\beta<(n+\mathrm f(n))\beta<\mathrm f(n+\mathrm f(n))<(n+\mathrm f(n))\beta+1<(n+n\beta+1)\beta+1.$$

Since $(n+n\beta)\beta=n$ and $\beta<1$, this yields 
$$n<\mathrm f(n+\mathrm f(n))<n+2.$$
Therefore $\mathrm f(n+\mathrm f(n))=n+1$, proving the claim.

Replacing $n$ with $n+1$ in this, we see that $\mathrm f(n+1+\mathrm f(n+1))=n+2$, and replacing the first $n+1$ in the last identity with $\mathrm f(n+\mathrm f(n))$ finally gives
$$\mathrm f(\mathrm f(n+\mathrm f(n))+\mathrm f(n+1))=n+2,$$
which means that $\mathrm f(n)$ satisfies the functional equation (and also the initial condition.)

(In no way does the above prove the uniqueness of this solution, but maybe someone else can have a go at that.)

The first few values of $\mathrm f(n)$ are seen in this table:
$$\begin{array}{|c|*12{c|}}
 \hline
 n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
\hline
 \mathrm f(n)&1&2&2&3&4&4&5&5&6&7&7&8\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Thus $\mathrm f(10)=7$.

Other interesting properties of $\mathrm f(n)$ are:

- $\mathrm f(\mathrm f(n))+\mathrm f(n+1)=n+2$,
- $\mathrm f(n+1)=\mathrm f(n)$ or $\mathrm f(n+1)=\mathrm f(n)+1$ for all $n$,
- if $\mathrm g:\Bbb N\mapsto\Bbb N$ is defined by $\mathrm g(1)=1$ and
  $$\mathrm g(n+1)=\begin{cases}\mathrm f(n), & \textrm{if }\mathrm f(n+1)=\mathrm f(n);\\
  \mathrm f(n)+n+1, & \textrm{if }\mathrm f(n+1)=\mathrm f(n)+1,\end{cases}$$
  then $\mathrm g:\Bbb N\mapsto\Bbb N$ is a bijection, with $\mathrm g(\mathrm g(n))=n$  and for which $\mathrm g(1)+\mathrm g(2)+\dots+\mathrm g(n)$ is divisible by $n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Nice! Can we similarly show uniqueness?